# Intersection of a complex line and an open set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and consider the following complex lines
$L_v: \{z+\tau v:\tau\in\mathbb{C}\}$, where $z\in\Omega$ and $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$. I have two questions:

1. Why it is not possible that for all $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ the intersection of $L_v$ and $\Omega$ be empty? ( we may say that $L_v$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $\Omega$ a subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$, but how would you right the details?)

2. Suppose $D$ is a disc that lies in $L_v$. What is the form of $D$?

Notice that in the definition of plurisubharmonic functions the intersection of a complex line and an open set of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is used.

Comment: Is $N=n?\,\,\,$

Comment: Yes. I corrected.

Comment: @Tuvasbien. Thanks, but $\left(\frac{\tau-z}{v}\right)$ is not in $\mathbb{C}$. How would you explain this?

Comment: No. $z$ belongs to $\Omega$ that is in $\mathbb{C}^n$, same for $v$.